# How to create background gradient effect in Flutter same as Apple TV app

Tags: flutter

How is best way to create Flutter background gradient effect used in Apple TV app as screenshot below. It looks like it is gradient from white to whitish-greyish in the background behind movie images.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `container` `BoxDecoration` `boxShadow` to achieve this.
here is a example

```
    class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 200,
      width: 200,
      child: Card(
        child: Center(
          child: Icon(
            Icons.movie,
            size: 150.0,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(boxShadow: [
        BoxShadow(
          color: Colors.white54,
          blurRadius: 10.0,
          offset: Offset(0, 10),
          spreadRadius: 0.5,
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: img]